# How to get default parameters listed in trigger pipeline popup of circleci?

Tags: pipeline, circleci

[image]

Below are the params that are present in my config file.

```
 region:
    type: string
    default: nonprod
  browser:
    type: string
    default: chrome
  tags:
    type: string
    default: priority1
  endCustomer:
    type: string
    default: excelBCustomers
```

When I click on trigger pipleine on circleci, I only see an option called pipline parameters(optional), which doesnt display the parameters which are added in the config file.

I don't have any insights on how to achieve this via circleci.

Is there a way to get the default params pre populated in circleci trigger pipeline popup?

Current option is to have them added manually and then trigger the pipeline, but that will be quite a tedious task when param list get bigger.

Comment: CircleCI doesn't support this at the moment. I hope they add this in the future.

Comment: I also need a feature like this one, I don't understand why they don’t show the default pipeline parameters.